# How to invoke a Java program/Batch from Jmeter, when there is a falure in sample

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan in Jmeter for Load testing purpose.Now it runs very often like whole night. When i see the results in morning, some of those http requests will be failed, but i couldn't get the reason from production logs.
Since my server is running on Tomcat, i am suspecting that there are too many threads spawned and in Waiting state or Dead Lock state. So i need to take a thread dump at the point of failure of sample.

Basically my question is, Is there a way we can invoke a external Batch/Java program to be invoked from Jmeter when there is a failure in http sample ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has a built-in variable holding the result of previous sampler execution: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` which returns `true` if preceding sampler was successful and `false` in other case.

So if you build your test plan as follows:

- HTTP Request
- If Controller, condition: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==false`

  - OS Process Sampler, configured to launch batch file or Java program

OS Process Sampler will be executed on the "HTTP Request" failure.

References:

- [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)
- [OS Process Sampler Official Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)